# Generate Invoice in PeopleSoft

Tags: oracle, peoplesoft

Has anyone here tried running Generate Invoice in PeopleSoft and encountered an error for its process instance? I can't pinpoint what is causing the error since when process monitor shows error - there are no log files to check.

Here are some additional files that may be useful

Server: PSNT
Process Type: COBOL SQL
Process Name: SFPBIPRC
Description: Invoice Batch Process

Does anyone knows how to debug this?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a COBOL question

Comment: You can turn on tracing by modifying the process definition and then rerunning the process.